# Spring Aspects will not run

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I've tried to add logging via Spring Aspects to my [project](https://github.com/ttheuer/sybil/tree/aoplogging), but the aspects never run.

This is the file where I define the aspects: LoggingInfo.java

```
package org.synyx.sybil.config;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;    

@Aspect
public class LoggingInfo {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingInfo.class);

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.tinkerforge.IPConnection.connect(String, int)) && args(host, port)")
    public void connect(String host, int port) {
    }


    @Before("connect(host, port)")
    public void CreateIPConnection(String host, int port) {

        LOG.info("Creating IPConnection to {}:{}", host, port);
    }`enter code here`


    @AfterReturning("connect(host, port)")
    public void FinishedCreatingIPConnection(String host, int port) {

        LOG.info("Successfully created IPConnection to {}:{}", host, port);
    }

    @AfterThrowing("connect(host, port)")
    public void FailedCreatingIPConnection(String host, int port) {

        LOG.info("Failed creating IPConnection to {}:{}", host, port);
    }
}
```

This is my Spring config: SpringConfigDev.java

```
package org.synyx.sybil.config;

import com.tinkerforge.AlreadyConnectedException;
import com.tinkerforge.BrickletLEDStrip;
import com.tinkerforge.IPConnection;
import com.tinkerforge.NotConnectedException;
import com.tinkerforge.TimeoutException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

import org.synyx.sybil.out.OutputLEDStrip;
import org.synyx.sybil.out.SingleStatusOnLEDStrip;
import org.synyx.sybil.out.SingleStatusOutput;

import java.io.IOException;


@Profile("dev")
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@PropertySource("classpath:SpringConfigDev.properties")
public class SpringConfigDev {

//    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringConfigDev.class);

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "disconnect")
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public IPConnection ipConnection() throws AlreadyConnectedException, IOException {

        String hostname = env.getRequiredProperty("ipconnection.hostname");
        int port = env.getProperty("ipconnection.port", Integer.class, 4223); // 4223 is the standard port

//        LOG.info("Creating IPConnection to {}:{}", hostname, port);

        IPConnection ipConnection = new IPConnection();
        ipConnection.connect(hostname, port);

//        LOG.info("Successfully connected to {}:{}", hostname, port);

        return ipConnection;
    }


    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public BrickletLEDStrip brickletLEDStrip(IPConnection ipConnection) throws TimeoutException, NotConnectedException {

        BrickletLEDStrip brickletLEDStrip = new BrickletLEDStrip(env.getRequiredProperty("brickletledstrip.uid"),
                ipConnection);
        brickletLEDStrip.setFrameDuration(10);
        brickletLEDStrip.setChipType(2812);

        return brickletLEDStrip;
    }


    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public OutputLEDStrip outputLEDStrip(BrickletLEDStrip brickletLEDStrip) {

        return new OutputLEDStrip(brickletLEDStrip, env.getRequiredProperty("outputledstrip.length", Integer.class));
    }


    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public SingleStatusOutput singleStatusOutput(OutputLEDStrip outputLEDStrip) {

        return new SingleStatusOnLEDStrip(outputLEDStrip);
    }
}
```

Everything in here works, execpt - apparently - for the @EnableAspectJAutoProxy.

This is the test I'm using to run it: OutputLEDStripTest.java

```
package org.synyx.sybil.out;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Test;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import org.synyx.sybil.config.SpringConfigDev;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SpringConfigDev.class })
public class OutputLEDStripTest {

    @Autowired
    private OutputLEDStrip outputLEDStrip;

    @After
    public void close() { // throws NotConnectedException {

        outputLEDStrip.setBrightness(1.0);
        outputLEDStrip.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        outputLEDStrip.updateDisplay();
    }


    @Test
    public void testSetColor() throws Exception {

        outputLEDStrip.setColor(new Color(16, 32, 8));
        outputLEDStrip.updateDisplay();

        Color pixel = outputLEDStrip.getPixel(0);
        assertEquals("Pixel 0.red should be 16", 16, pixel.getRed());
        assertEquals("Pixel 0.green should be 32", 32, pixel.getGreen());
        assertEquals("Pixel 0.blue should be 8", 8, pixel.getBlue());
    }


    @Test
    public void testSetPixel() throws Exception {

        Color color = new Color(16, 35, 77);

        outputLEDStrip.setPixel(1, color);
        outputLEDStrip.updateDisplay();

        Color pixel0 = outputLEDStrip.getPixel(0);
        Color pixel1 = outputLEDStrip.getPixel(1);

        assertEquals("Pixel 0.red should be 0", 0, pixel0.getRed());
        assertEquals("Pixel 0.green should be 0", 0, pixel0.getGreen());
        assertEquals("Pixel 0.blue should be 0", 0, pixel0.getBlue());
        assertEquals("Pixel 1.red should be 16", 16, pixel1.getRed());
        assertEquals("Pixel 1.green should be 35", 35, pixel1.getGreen());
        assertEquals("Pixel 1.blue should be 77", 77, pixel1.getBlue());
    }


    @Test
    public void testSetBrightnessHalf() throws Exception {

        outputLEDStrip.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        outputLEDStrip.setBrightness(.5);
        outputLEDStrip.updateDisplay();

        Color pixel = outputLEDStrip.getPixel(0);
        assertTrue("Pixel 0 should be half as bright as a full white (127, 127, 127).",
            pixel.getRed() == (short) (127 * .5) && pixel.getGreen() == (short) (127 * .5)
            && pixel.getBlue() == (short) (127 * .5));
    }


    @Test
    public void testSetBrightnessFull() throws Exception {

        outputLEDStrip.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        outputLEDStrip.setBrightness(1);
        outputLEDStrip.updateDisplay();

        Color pixel = outputLEDStrip.getPixel(0);
        assertTrue("Pixel 0 should be full white (127, 127, 127).",
            pixel.getRed() == 127 && pixel.getGreen() == 127 && pixel.getBlue() == 127);
    }


    @Test
    public void testSetBrightnessDouble() throws Exception {

        outputLEDStrip.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        outputLEDStrip.setBrightness(2);
        outputLEDStrip.updateDisplay();

        Color pixel = outputLEDStrip.getPixel(0);
        assertTrue("Pixel 0 should be double as bright as a full white (127, 127, 127).",
            pixel.getRed() == (short) (127 * 2) && pixel.getGreen() == (short) (127 * 2)
            && pixel.getBlue() == (short) (127 * 2));
    }
}
```

You won't be able to sucessfully run this project unless you install the Tinkerforge brickd damon and have a Tinkerforge brick with a LED Strip bricklet connected somewhere and the SpringConfigDev.properties file set up for it.
**But**, if logging worked, you should see the error messages in the log file.

Comment: Your aspect isn't added as a bean so the aspectj support doesn't know about the aspect and it will be happily ignored.

Comment: How would I go about that? Just adding
     @Bean

    public LoggingInfo loggingInfo() {

        LoggingInfo loggingInfo = new LoggingInfo();

        return loggingInfo;
    }
Does not seem to help

Comment: The ipConnection.connect(hostname, port) in the ipConnection() will not trigger the aspect as the ipConnect is instantiated per new.

Comment: Further you need to call the connect outside the place where you call the new.

Comment: @TobiasTheuer As M.Deinum answered, your aspects needs to be also Spring beans. Just annotate them via Component annotation

Comment: Even if you add it as a bean it will not work. You are calling connect yourself inside a bean method. That way Spring will never be able to proxy it to intercept the methods. You will have to use either lead-time or compile time weaving to make it work with your current setup.

Comment: What about putting the initialization code into @PostConstruct-annotated method on the IPConnection class, such method gets executed automatically and the execution might also trigger the aspect. You still need to have LoggingInfo as bean.

Comment: @kriegaex I accepted your answer, but I cannout upvote yet ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring configuration hints are all okay, but I guess they will not help because the pointcut says:

```java
execution(* com.tinkerforge.IPConnection.connect(String, int))
```

The thing is: I assume that the Tinkerforge classes are not Spring components, i.e. they cannot be targeted by Spring AOP `execution()` pointcuts. So either you switch to [full AspectJ](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj) and use a `call()` pointcut (unavailable in Spring AOP) or as a workaround you change your pointcut to target one of your Spring components' methods which has the same information. **;-)**